# Using ant and netbeans how can I generate a UML diagram

Tags: netbeans, ant, uml

We are trying to include the generation of an UML diagram on build via a task in ant.

So far I can't seem to find an easy way to do this and everything seem to point to eclipse.

We are using NetBeans 7.1.

Any pointers on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which UML diagrams do you want to generate? If you want to generate the class and sequence diagrams for a use case, [MaintainJ](http://maintainj.com) is an option.

If you have JUnit test cases for your application, you can generate the class and sequence diagrams for every test case. Check this [demo video](http://maintainj.com/userGuide.jsp?param=junitRuntimeDemo).

You should probably view this [demo video](http://maintainj.com/userGuide.jsp?param=overviewDemo) to get an overview of MaintainJ.

Once you understand how to generate the diagrams for every JUnit test case, it is quite easy to integrate it with Ant script. This way, for every new build, you could run all the test cases and generate the UML diagrams for all the test cases.

I am the author of MaintainJ, by the way.

Comment: Interesting product. Tho as it's only a student project for one session I would be unlikely to buy a licence only for this.

Comment: Erick, MaintainJ is free for students. Contact MaintainJ support if you would like to use it on other projects

Comment: is MaintainJ available for Netbeans 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a question about the IDE you're using when you want to do this with ant. You have to find a ant plugin/task that can generate graphics out of your class hierarchy.

I only now plugins generating code out of UML diagramms but not the other way round, but a solution for you could be to develop your own ant task maby using ImageMagick to generate the diagramm.